# How to update a Windows Form textbox value while waiting for a web response

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to update a status message while waiting for a web response to be returned. The call posts files to a server and sometimes it can take 30+ seconds.

I want to update the message (windows form textbox text) if the call is taking longer than expected. If the call has been waiting for 15 seconds, update the message to "This is taking awhile but should complete soon."

I've tried:

- async fire and forget
- timer using invoke
- task.run
- both tasks as async, awaiting the web calling Tasks
- Background Worker using dowork and progress work

Nothing seems to work. Is it even possible to update the main thread while a task has a thread locked up?

I'm testing with simple calls:

```
private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    while (!worker.CancellationPending)
    {
        Task.Delay(1000).Wait();
        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            this.box.Text += '.';
            this.box.Update();
        });
    }
}

private void MakeCall()
{
    worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
        //Just runs Task.Delay(10000) then returns "Complete"
        var res = client.DownloadString("https://localhost:44343/api/TestDelay");
        MessageBox.Show(res);
    }
    worker.CancelAsync();
}

private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MakeCall();
}
```

Comment: You would need to invoke the textbox in order to update the text. `this.Invoke` isn't a textbox. Also given above in `StartMinder` with it being marked as `async`, using `invoke` contradicts the method because `invoke` is a blocking call as well.

Comment: Also, `private async Task MakeCall()` VS should be throwing up because you're not `await`ing anything in that routine.

Comment: It does give the standard no awaits error but i had it marked async as part of my testing to try and get them to work as needed. Switching invoke to this.box.invoke also did not work.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ  You can invoke the parent. That's the intended marshaler anyway.

Comment: @Jimi I know you can, I didn't say you couldn't. Why would the OP invoke the parent anyways in this case?

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ  Since the TextBox has a Parent, the Parent it will be the marshaler anyway. But this is not the point of this question. What has been done to resolve the *issue* is not exactly clear.  The role of `StartMinder()` is undefined in this context, that's nothing that relates one method to the other.

Comment: @jimi The two methods are what im trying to get to run at the same time. I didnt include the code in which i used them because nothing is working. Basically, run StartMinder() (without waiting for complete), run MakeCall() and let StartMinder continue working while MakeCall is waiting for the web response

Comment: You can use the Task based download method: [WebClient.DownloadFileTaskAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloadfiletaskasync) or the event-driven one: [WebClient.DownloadFileAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloadfileasync). You can check the time elasped  and report progress, if you want to. See the [DownloadProgressChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloadprogresschanged) event. Remove the BackGroundWorker.

Comment: `worker_DoWork` you should be handling updates to the text property through [Progress Changed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.progresschanged?view=netframework-4.8) event.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ I've tried that as well

Comment: Delete everything and start from scratch, using one of the two different asynchronous methods linked before. One is Task based, the other event-based. Pick the one you're more confortable with, the result is the same.

Comment: `I've tried that as well` where is this code? Currently the question lacks clarity; you said you've tried this and that, but I'm not seeing these implementations along with what is wrong. Please update your post to include *the code you are actually working with*. To be honest starting over would be best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I see your problem. You are downloading on the UI thread without ever getting off of it, so the background worker can never get on it either.

Try this code out:

EDIT: Using two Tasks rather than a background worker

```
private void MakeCall()
{
    // it'd be a good idea to disable the button here
    ManualResetEventSlim waiter = new ManualResetEventSlim(false);
    Task.Run(async () => 
    {
        while(!waiter.IsSet) 
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000);  
            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                this.box.Text += '.';
                this.box.Update();
            });                
        } 
    });
    Task.Run(() => 
    {
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            var res = client.DownloadString("https://localhost:44343/api/TestDelay");
            MessageBox.Show(res);
        }

        waiter.Set();
        // hop back on the UI thread and re-enable your button here
    });
}

private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MakeCall();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried this method an the results are still the same. worker_DoWork doesnt run until MakeCall is complete

Comment: @Seth Ok, try it with the latest updated code I put on there.  If that doesn't work, just shoot me now.

Comment: Actually, Your first suggestion worked (I think both will actually). My build was on the wrong version and just didn't show the proper results. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm providing an additional answer here because although the answer by outbred worked in my test, it didnt work in my original program because the form needed to remain open, locking the main form, run one of the defined tasks, then close automatically. That meant the async fire and forget method wasn't an option. 
What I did was overloaded the forms ShowDialog method to take an async action, trigger it, show the dialog, then close the dialog on complete. 
This method works perfectly, locking the parent and allowing the background worker to update the text.

```
internal DialogResult ShowDialog(Action action) => ShowDialog(async () => await Task.Run(action));
internal DialogResult ShowDialog(Func<Task> action)
{
    action.Invoke().ContinueWith(task => this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK);
    return this.ShowDialog();
}
```

Then you can call it using one of the following ways:

```
using (Form1 form = new Form1())
    form.ShowDialog(form.MakeCall);
```

```
using (Form1 form = new Form1())
    form.ShowDialog(() => { form.MakeCall("HelloWorld");} );
```

```
using (Form1 form = new Form1())
    form.ShowDialog(async () => { await form.MakeCallAsync("HelloWorld");} );
```

It will display the form as a dialog (locking the parent), run the task to completion, then close the form.